# Using VueJS 2.0 and a vue-mdl menu component, how do I respond to click events?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

It doesn't seem to respond to `@click` but `v-bind:click` does register. However, I can't put a method in the directive since I can't access the `mdl-menu` or `mdl-menu-item` components to add the method.

I'm trying to do something like `@click="setStatus('field-name', 'value')"` with four menu options (each with a different `value`, same `field-name`).

I feel like there's either an element of VueJS I'm not yet aware of or it's going to be something fancy with Events.

I tried adding inline code `bus.$emit('event', 'data')`, but nothing happens (no errors, nothing in console, nothing)

Sample element:

```
<span class="bar" v-on:click="clicked">
  <mdl-button icons raised colored
              v-bind:id="generateId('av')"
              v-bind:class="getButtonClass(row.avStatus)"
              v-bind:title="row.avStatus"
  >
      <i class="material-icons">videocam</i>
  </mdl-button>

  <mdl-menu v-bind:for="generateId('av')">
      <mdl-menu-item data-field="avStatus">Open</mdl-menu-item>
      <mdl-menu-item data-field="avStatus">In Progress</mdl-menu-item>
      <mdl-menu-item data-field="avStatus">Review</mdl-menu-item>
      <mdl-menu-item data-field="avStatus">Ready</mdl-menu-item>
  </mdl-menu>
</span>
```

**Edit 1**:

So I got the click event to *work* last night, but I'm not sure it's the correct method (feels very messy).

What I did was add the `v-on:click="clicked"` listener to the parent `span`, then within the `clicked()` method I have:

```
if (e.target.className == "mdl-menu__item") { /* code */ }
```

To only act when the menu options are clicked. This feels...wrong. Shouldn't I be able to add a listener directly to the menu option, or *at least* to the parent `mdl-menu`?

Comment: Can you add relevant code segment or create a jsfiddle of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use the `.native` modifier on the `click`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events). When using `v-on` on a component rather than a native html node, vue only look for the event among the child component's custom events declared with `$emit`, add `.native` will make vue treat it as a native event.